# How to make GXT grid header editable

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I am trying to make an editable grid using GXT 3.1.0. I am facing issues in making grid header editable. I have used GridInlineEditing for all grid rows.

I am trying to open an editor on click of the header but unable to do that. Can I make grid header editable? If that is complicated or not possible.

Comment: I would do it with grid.addHeaderClickHandler and grid.getView().getHeader().setHeader(int column, SafeHtml text).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already figured out a way to done my job.
I have updated columnConfig.setWidget to combobox on header click which changes my header to a combobox on header click. Similarly added a blur handler on combobox to update grid header from the combo box.